# Converting Rows in a Data Frame to .txt document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working with a large data frame in python where each row needs to be converted to a text document.  The code I have causes the iPython terminal to crash and restart never getting through the first line of the data frame. 
The df is able to load correctly however, the conversion does not run correctly.

Is there a work around or another method to covert the rows to individual text documents?

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel(open('C:\\example.xlsx','rb'), sheetname='list')

i =0
for row in df.values:
    file_title = 'C:\\document{}.txt'.format(i)
    row.tofile(file_title, sep=",", format="%s")
i+0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write each row of pandas dataframe into a new text file - pythonic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620132/write-each-row-of-pandas-dataframe-into-a-new-text-file-pythonic-way)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620132/write-each-row-of-pandas-dataframe-into-a-new-text-file-pythonic-way

Comment: I discovered that there is a limit on the words amount that pandas can handle in a cell.  On average my cells contain 4300 words each.  By using the write function, and not pandas, I was able to generate the required data.