# How to covert each row of a csv file to a separate text file?

Tags: python, pandas, yolo

I have this data:

[image]

Now I want to convert each row of this csv file to text file and the text file name should be the name of the first element of the row (i.e. 0d4b3896f938d981.txt) and the text file will contain only the elements of Column 1 to 5 (i.e. 3 0.372070 0.873913 0.066406 0.158261)

Comment: Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620132/write-each-row-of-pandas-dataframe-into-a-new-text-file-pythonic-way)

Comment: To get answers, include information on what you have tried, language used, etc. To improve readability, link only a word or two to the spreadsheet image.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i can try this :

```
import csv
import os 

base = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
csv_file open(base + "/any.csv", mode='r')
dialect = csv.excel()
dialect.delimiter = ';'
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, dialect=dialect)
txt_file open(base + "/any.csv", mode='w') 
txt_file = txt.writer()

for row in csv_reader:
   txt_file.writerow((row, ))

txt_file.save()
txt_file.close()
csv_file.close()
```

I hope it helps you, greetings.